# Good alternatives to "key"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Examples: Key developer, key customer.
Task: Replace "key" without losing the meaning.

For a developer I could use "principal" but it's possible that there is already a principal developer who isn't the key developer for a particular application.

[Thesaurus lists some options](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/key?s=t) but none of them are as good as "key":
crucial, major, primary. Crucial customer? Major developer?

Comment: @Drew You didn't read my whole question, did you? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no better alternative, that is why the term has been used figuratively for more than a century now:

***Key (adj.) :***

> - ***"crucially important," 1913, from key perhaps from or reinforced by key move, in chess,***  "first move in a solution to a set problem" (1827), which to an experienced player opens the way to see how the solution will develop.

Etymonline